# How to show selected columns in downloaded excel using xlsx Angular 8

Tags: angular, xlsx

My requirement to download an excelsheet. It used service response to generate excel sheet.

My Problem is, received json contains aditional parametes few of them are not required to display in downloded excel. I have to restrict to show them in excel.

Can anyone tell me how can add check to stop populating un necessory columns.

I am using xlsx, angular8

Answer (score 0):

Briefly & abstract: that is a mapping problem; you want a subset of the delivered set.

I'd create an "ideal" object "MyObject" (i.e. the xlsx-columns you desire with the names as they are coming out of the consumed service)

Then, I'd iterate through the service response and create a new instance of "MyObject" per row (i.e. MyRowObject.varName1 = ServiceIncomingRowObject.varName1).